# Why this regex pattern fails to match a given string and how to correct it?

Tags: python, regex

I want to **capture all characters** using python **regex** which satisfy **one of the three conditions** described below.

(`~` means zero or more characters)

[pattern1] `NAME_` ”words_or_numbers” `AGE_` `my_num` ~;

[pattern2] `NAME_` ”words_or_numbers” `DESC_` `my_num` ~;

[pattern3] `NAME_ADD_` ”words_or_numbers” `CHAR_DESC_ADD_` word_or_numbers_or_underscore DESC_ `my_num` ~;

For [pattern1], [pattern2], [pattern3], I’d like to find only the text that **matches the given `my_num`**. For example, the example below indicates that I picked 373 and 416 as the `my_num` values.

(Note that each pattern can contain multiline characters)

Original Text:

```bash
NAME_ "Hello" AGE_ 373 0;
NAME_ "Summer" AGE_ 340 0;
NAME_ "Sam" AGE_ 416 14;
NAME_ "Edward" DESC_ 373 ABC_DEF_G "These are users.

age, description

- example(0x15) , Isfalse : 0xF+df

- safe.

- (t) = + 1";
NAME_ "Alex" DESC_ 373 asdf 65535;
NAME_ADD_ "Crystal" CHAR_DESC_ADD_ GGE_R DESC_ 373 ABCD 340;
NAME_ "Ray" DESC_ 111 asdfs 3;
NAME_ "Brown" DESC_ 416 asdfs 3;
NAME_ADD_ "Hailey" CHAR_DESC_ADD_ GGE3 DESC_ 416 ABCD 120;
NAME_ "Watson" AGE_ 373 0;
NOT_NAME_ 324 XYZ 22 "A" 1 "B" 2 "C" 3 "R" ;
```

Desired Output:

```bash
NAME_ "Hello" AGE_ 373 0;
NAME_ "Sam" AGE_ 416 14;
NAME_ "Edward" DESC_ 373 ABC_DEF_G "These are users.

age, description

- example(0x15) , Isfalse : 0xF+df

- safe.

- (t) = + 1";
NAME_ "Alex" DESC_ 373 asdf 65535;
NAME_ADD_ "Crystal" CHAR_DESC_ADD_ GGE_R DESC_ 373 ABCD 340;
NAME_ "Brown" DESC_ 416 asdfs 3;
NAME_ADD_ "Hailey" CHAR_DESC_ADD_ GGE3 DESC_ 416 ABCD 120;
NAME_ "Watson" AGE_ 373 0;
```

I’ve tried using regex like (with re.findall method):

```bash
(?s)((NAME_ .+ (AGE_|DESC_) (373|416) .?(?=NAME_|NOT_NAME_|$))|(NAME_ADD_ .+ CHAR_DESC_ADD_ .+ DESC_ (373|416) .?(?=NAME_|NOT_NAME_|$)))
```

but it captured nothing. What's wrong with my attempt, and how can this be done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem I see with the regex is that you only match space and single optional character after the `my_num`. In your original text there is no sequence that matches this, so that is why the result is empty. Also the `.+` should be changed to exclude the `;` character, otherwise the regex could match the whole file as long as the first and last few of characters together match one of the patterns.

You could change the `.+` to `[^;]+` and the `.?` after `my_num` to `[^;]*;`. The `[^;]` matches any character that is not `;`. Also if you do this the lookahead assertion `(?=NAME_|NOT_NAME_|$)` is not needed. The new regex could look like this:

```
(?s)((NAME_ [^;]+ (AGE_|DESC_) (373|416) [^;]*;)|(NAME_ADD_ [^;]+ CHAR_DESC_ADD_ [^;]+ DESC_ (373|416) [^;]*;))
```

Comment: Nice @m77m77, I want to add one thing if there is a word boundary before `NAME_`, and before `NAME_ADD_`, this will prevent things like `NOT_NAME_ "Hello" AGE_ 373 0;` and `NOT_NAME_ADD_ "Crystal" CHAR_DESC_ADD_ GGE_R DESC_ 373 ABCD 340;`,